# CSS3 column-count issue on iOS

Tags: ios, css, column-count

Is there any workaround?

I have applied

```
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 5; 
 column-count: 5;
}
```

but its not working on iOS .

Comment: not working in mac safari?

Comment: iPad iOS 9.2.1 is my version